# Passing ...props to styles show type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

I want to have possiblity to add more styles for button if i have to ,but if I do it by this way but i get error.

I pass type to it is to FunctionComponent type to annotate anonymous functions. FunctionComponent also adds a type for children(it is type from preact)

```
import type { FunctionComponent } from "preact";
import type { HTMLAttributes } from "preact/compat";


export const ButtonSecondary: FunctionComponent<{ [props: string]: HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> }> = ({ children, ...props }) => (
    <button class={`border-gray-800 border-4 bg-white rounded-md hover:  py-4 px-3 text-center font-bold text-gray-800 text-base cursor-pointer hover:translate-y-2 duration-150 
    ${...props}
`}>
        {children}
    </button>
)
```

Comment: in your Button: change `class` by `className=`

Comment: In preact it is prefered to use class preactjs.com/guide/v8/differences-to-react/#whats-added

Comment: oh sorry i did not notice it was preact.. Well if you log your props what you get as a result ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally a particular prop should be providing the extra styling, rather than *all* the props (as your current code is doing).

So, if you're using `ButtonSecondary` as follows:

```js
  <ButtonSecondary
     extraClasses="anotherClass andAnother"
  >
```

You just make use of `${props.extraClasses}`.
You don't want to limit your props to only provide data that will be used in one specific place in your component.

Also, the way you've defined the props for this component can be improved. Maybe use something like:

```js
 type ButtonProps = {
  extraClasses: string,
  otherStuff?: string
 }
...
export const ButtonSecondary: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps>
```